# How to convert google formula to excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help me convert simple formula for auto increment with condition - `=Arrayformula(if(D2:D="",,countifs(D2:D, D2:D, row(D2:D), "<="&row(D2:D))))`

I've tried to use the following, but it doesn't work:

```
{=if(D2:D2000="","",countifs(D2:D2000, D2:D2000, row(D2:D2000), "<="&row(D2:D2000)))}
```

I get the error "There's a problem with this formula".

Here is the expected result (column E)

[image]

Comment: That's not a valid COUNTIFS formula in Excel (you can only use ranges not arrays for the criteria range). What are you trying to do and which version do you have?

Comment: I'm trying to create the following logic - if the value in the D column is the same, create autoincrement number for the current column. And start again from 1, when the value is different in column D. I have excel 365.

Comment: Could you please post a data input and expected output?

Comment: I've added it to my question

Comment: @MaksymKatsovets in Excel it is pretty simple, you just need to use this `=IF(D2="","",COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2))`

Comment: And If you have access to `LAMBDA()` --> You can define it in a name manager, `=LAMBDA(a,COUNTIF($D$2:D2,D2))` --> **Auto(a)**

Comment: Thanks.
Is it possible to use it as an array formula? Just add it for 1st line and get a result for all?

Comment: I don't think so, may be some one has better idea on it, however i would suggest to go through this documentation from Microsoft on how [Spill Array works](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531)

Comment: You could use Match instead for a spill formula - =ROW(D1:D7)-MATCH(D1:D7,D1:D7,0)+1 assuming data sorted and starting in first row.